# C declarations before usage

Tags: c

All identifiers in C need to be declared before they are used, but I can`t find where it denoted in C99 standard.

I think it refers to macro definitions too, but there is only macro expansion order defined.

Answer (score 5):

C99:TC3 6.5.1 §2, with footnote 79 explicitly stating:

> > Thus, an undeclared identifier is a violation of the syntax.

in conjunction with 6.2.1 §5:

> > Unless explicitly stated otherwise, [...] it [*ie an identifier*] refers to the
> >     entity in the relevant name space **whose declaration is visible at the point the identifier
> >     occurs**.

and §7:

> > [...] Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.

Comment: So, what is "undeclared" then? I mean, if identifier declared after usage, why it is called "undeclared"? Thanks.

Comment: @S.J.: an undeclared identifier is an identifier that you try to use before/without declaring it. If you write `printf("%d",a);` without having an `int a;` (declaration+definition) before, `a` is an undeclared identifier (and thus a violation of the syntax).

Comment: @S.J. when undeclared - there is no information about variable's size and its structure

Comment: @S.J.: added second quote from the scoping section; the term 'undeclared' is only used in that footnote, but it means that no declaration of the identifier is visible (see bold text above)

Comment: @Christoph: what I try to understand, is a 6.2.1 §7: "Any other identiﬁer has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator". Now this question is clear for me, thank you...

Answer (score 2):

There are a at least couple of exceptions to the rule that all identifiers need to be delcared before use:

- while C99 removed implicit function declarations, you may still see C programs that rely, possibly unknowingly, on them.  There is even the occasional question on SO that, for example, ask why functions that return `double` don't work (when the header that includes the declaration of the function is omitted). It seems that when compiling with pre-C99 semantics, warnings for undeclared functions are often not configured to be used or are ignored.
- the identifier for a `goto` label may be used before it's 'declaration' - it is declared implicitly by its syntactic appearance (followed by a : and a statement).

The exception to the rule for `goto` labels is pretty much a useless nitpick, but the fact that function identifiers can be used without a declaration (pre-C99) is something that can be useful to know because you might once in a while run into a problem with it as a root cause.

Also, identifiers can be used before being 'declared' (strictly speaking, before being defined) in preprocessing, where they can be tested for being defined or not, or used in preprocessor expressions where they will evaluate to `0` if not otherwise defined.